# Conic neighborhoods ⇔ polyhedral

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, reference-request

I am looking for a reference to the following fact (I can prove it
my-self, but it should be known for a century).

> Let $X$ be a *reasonable* metric space such that each point has a spherical
>   neighborhood which is isometric to a cone. Then $X$ is a polyhedral space.

Reasonable means say *compact* plus *finite Hausdorff dimension* (I
would be happy with anything which includes finite dimensional
Alexandrov space).

**Definitions:**

- A finite simplicial complex $P$ with a metric is called *polyhedral
  space* if each simplex in $P$ is isometric to a flat simplex.
- A space $K$ is called *cone* if there is a metric space $\Sigma$
  and $r>0$ such that $K$ is isometric to $\Sigma\times[0,r]$ with
  metric defined by the law of cosines;  i.e.
  $$|(\xi,x)(\zeta,z)|^2=x^2+y^2-2xy\cos\alpha,$$ where $\alpha$ is the
  distance from $\xi$ to $\zeta$ in $\Sigma$.

Comment: I guess in the definition of a cone you meant to say that $r\alpha$ is the distance from $\xi$ to $\zeta$ in $\Sigma$?

Answer (score 1):

Just to close the question:
a proof is written in our note ["Local characterization of polyhedral spaces"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.6670).